# Update Error in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

When I'm running `sudo apt-get update` I am getting following errors/exceptions. Give me some solutions..

```
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.kavalinux.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.kavalinux.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: Try changing your server to the main server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a desktop or server edition? If desktop, try the following:

- open System settings and click Software & Updates;
- click the "Download from" field and select "Main server";
- launch Software updater (or run `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get upgrade`)